# what is a best way to compare two list<Custom>

Tags: c#, list, compare

```
class MasterList
{
    public int ID = int.MinValue;
    public DateTime LastUpdated = DateTime.MinValue;

    public MasterList(String sId, String sLastUpdated)
    {
        sId = ("" + sId).Trim();
        sLastUpdated = ("" + sLastUpdated).Trim();
        if (sId != "" && sLastUpdated != "")
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(sId);
            LastUpdated = Convert.ToDateTime(sLastUpdated);
        }
    }
}

List<MasterList> MostUpdatedListFromDataProvider;
List<MasterList> LocalDBList;
```

How can I find out IDs to ADD and IDs to Update in two separate list. Need two separate list 1. To add new products 2. update products.

I tried this for getting IDsToUpdate.

```
public static List<int> IDsToUpdate(List<MasterList> DDF, List<MasterList> DB)
    {
        List<int> IDs = new List<int>();

        foreach (MasterList ml in DDF)
        {
            MasterList q = (from dbb in DB
                            where dbb.ID.Equals(ml.ID)
                            where dbb.LastUpdated < ml.LastUpdated
                            select dbb).SingleOrDefault();
            if (q != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IDsToUpdate: " + ml.ID);
                IDs.Add(ml.ID);
            }
        }

        return IDs;
    }
```

but that is super slow.

Comment: what is the _purpose_ of this:   `("" + sId).Trim();`

Comment: trim the input string properly since there is lot of variation in incoming data.

Comment: @Selman22 I suspect it's an elaborate alternative to `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sId)`

Comment: thats right Barrick. But any answer to the question. I am dealing with millions of records and the process is damn slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to find out which `MasterList` items are in the `MostUpdatedListFromDataProvider` that are not in the `LocalDBList`, then get `MasterList` to implement `IEquatable<MasterList>` and provide the relevant comparison in the `Equals()` method in the class (don't forget to override GetHashCode() too):

```
class MasterList : IEquatable<MasterList>
{
    public int ID = int.MinValue;
    public DateTime LastUpdated = DateTime.MinValue;

    public MasterList(String sId, String sLastUpdated)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sId) && 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sLastUpdated))
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(sID);
            LastUpdated = Convert.ToDateTime(sLastUpdated);      
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(MasterList other)
    {
        return (this.ID == other.ID &&
                this.LastUpdated == other.LastUpdated);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ID.GetHashCode() * this.LastUpdated.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that `sId` and `sLastUpdated` will convert to `int` and `DateTime` - you may wish to add further checks for this.

Now that's in place, you can use `Enumerable.Except` to retrieve the differences between the two `Lists`:

```
var differences = MostUpdatedListFromDataProvider.Except(LocalDBList);
```

Depending on the size of each `List`, you may find different performance if you swap them around e.g.

```
var differences = LocalDBList.Except(MostUpdatedListFromDataProvider);
```

as one `List` will be read entirely into memory whilst the other is streamed, but it may be that the quicker way doesn't meet your requirements.